# terminal vim not loading .zshrc

Tags: vim, zsh, zshrc

My terminal vim configuration is not loading the ~/.zshrc. Zsh is the environment login shell. What is the proper configuration for this situation?

Here are some measures I've already taken and since removed:

`set shell=zsh`
(uses zsh as shell but doesn't source the rc)

`set shellcmdflag=-ci`
(all output suspended)

`cat ~/.zshenv

$ source ~/.zshrc`
(many errors when opening vim)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the manual:

> ```
> Commands  are  first  read from /etc/zshenv; this cannot be overridden.
>
> [...]
>
> Commands are then read from $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv. If the shell is a
> login shell, commands are read from /etc/zprofile and then 
> $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile. Then, if the shell is interactive, 
> commands are read from /etc/zshrc and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc. Finally,
> if the shell is a login shell, /etc/zlogin and $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin are
> read.
> ```

From what I understand,

```
set shell=zsh\ -i
```

should work.

Comment: that's the second command in `set shellcmdflag=-ci`. when i try that, all the output is suspended.

Comment: `-ci` or `-i` are the correct flags. Do you mean that vim is suspended and you are at the shell's prompt? That's the expected and normal behaviour of Vim in a terminal. You won't be able to change it at all. In GVim/MacVim, doing `:!<command>` expands the command-line into a sort of dumb terminal for you to read the output of `<command>`. If that's the behaviour you are after you'll have to switch to GVim/MacVim.

Comment: With either the `ci` or `c` flags, commands finish with something like `21195 suspended (tty output)  vim` and I am left at the zsh shell prompt. I then have to type `fg` to have the expected result.

Comment: @slm the manual entry provides the insight you need to resolve the issue. my problem was related to the read order of commands.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer doesn't work as expected. The actual solution should be putting the aliases and other `~/.zshrc` content into `~/.zshenv`. The only thing needed in `~/.vimrc` is `set shell=zsh` without any flags.

Comment: the manual entry provides the insight you need to resolve the issue. my problem was related to the read order of commands. nowhere were aliases mentioned as being a problem.

Comment: A bit smoother. Add a symlink `ln -s ~/.zshrc ~/.zshenv `

Answer (score 1):

I found an handy solution. As the only thing I really need is all my aliases, I added a function to my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
function zshalias()
{
  grep "^alias" ~/.zshrc > ~/.zshenv
}
```

Then execute `source ~/.zshrc && zshalias`.

In your vimrc you only need:

```
shell=zsh
```

Everything then works perfectly with no suspended tty output!