# Run command line via alias with zsh on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, shell, alias, zsh

I use the `system/unix` command on Matlab in order to run an external program via the command line. I want to execute it via an alias define in `.zshrc` on my computer. Unfortunately, the alias seems to be not available.

**Example with ll**

- on a terminal: `which ll` gives `ll: aliased to ls -lh`
- on Matlab: `unix('ll')` gives `zsh:1: command not found: ll`

I check if I used the right shell: `unix('echo $SHELL')` gives `/usr/local/bin/zsh`.

I have add `setopt aliases` in my `.zshrc` but it changes nothing. Is it possible to check which startup files is used when you open a non interactive shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~/.zshrc` seems to be not loaded in the non interactive case. The solution consists in loaded aliases and added `setopt aliases` in `~/.zshenv`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055613/zshell-aliases-like-gst-inside-vim) for instance.